# download a word document using Apache POI generates a corrupted document

Tags: apache-poi, httpresponse, java-6, office-2013

I created a word document using Apache POI API and can write the file to my local machine and it works very well but when writing to `response.getOutputStream()` to be able to allow the user to download using the browser, the word document gets corrupted.

Here's my code:

```
String docFile =  "inv_export_012.docx";
FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\" + docFile);

//set response headers
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + docFile);
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");

//create docx format using XWPFDocument
XWPFDocument wordDocument = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph p1 = wordDocument.createParagraph();
p1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
XWPFRun r1 = p1.createRun();
r1.setText("Invoice Number: 00000000XXX");
r1.addCarriageReturn();

//write document to local C: drive
//this step works well and I can successfully create the document
wordDocument.write(fos);

//set content length
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(new File("C:\\temp\\" + docFile).length()));
fos.close();
wordDocument.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

Also tried the binary formats and it doesn't work either.

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

- Java version: 1.6 (Can't update to new version yet)
- Apache POI: 3.16
- Browser: Internet Explorer 11 (My application is only certified in IE so can't use other
  browsers)
- Office 2013

It works well and document is created successfully on my local desktop. If I try to download using the browser and open it directly (or save it and open it), below error appears indicating document is corrupt. Clicking to open the document still opens the document but anyone knows why I am getting this message? Any help would be appreciated!!

[image]

Clicking OK I get this message:

[image]

### If I Click 'Yes' it does open the document.

**EDIT: 06/29**- Updated the code to generate *.docx format. Also added Content-Length in the response header. Tried by removing the Content-Length too both of which didn't work.

Comment: "It works well and document is created successfully on my local desktop.": Then something went wrong with the download approach and not with `apache poi`. But we do not see the whole code. Where is `contentLength`coming from? Maybe it is wrong? Why are you naming a `XWPFDocument` `*.doc`? It should be `*.docx` instead.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this @AxelRichter.  contentLength is just a hard-coded int value. This is a simple one liner document so I set the contentLength to 4000. Yes I too believe something gets corrupted when downloading. I have tried both *.docx format and *.doc as you could see in the question.

Comment: The `Content-Length` header should either be correct (the count of bytes of the file) or not used. It never should be any incorrect value. What happens if you simply do not using it? And my hint to `*.docx` was because of the file name. A `XWPFDocument` belongs always in a `*.docx` file. A  `HWPFDocument` belongs in a `*.doc` file.

Comment: Updated the code to generate `*.docx` format as suggested. Also added `Content-Length` in the response header. Tried by removing the `Content-Length` too both of which didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Found out that POI 3.16 has this problem, this issue is resolved when I upgraded to Apache POI 4.0.0 jar.